# Why am I getting this unhandled exception error?

Tags: java, javafx, unhandled-exception

I am trying to fire the `test()` method (which uses elements from the JAudioTagger library) when a JavaFX Button is clicked:

```
search.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        test();
    }
});
```

And here is the `test()` method:

```
public void test() throws CannotReadException, IOException, TagException, ReadOnlyFileException, InvalidAudioFrameException {
    ...
}
```

For some reason, Eclipse has underlined the reference to test() in the first bit of code, saying that

```
Unhandled exception type InvalidAudioFrameException
```

even though this exception has already been handled in the `test()` method? I don't get it.

Comment: I have no idea why folks are answering a question that has obviously been asked previously a gazillion times.

Comment: [Take your pick of a duplicate question](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=unhandled+exception+type+java+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Answer (score 0):

Your test method 'claims' it throws the exception.
If you declare it in your throws clause, the caller of the method must be prepared to either catch it or add it to it's throws clause.

Comment: I tried adding the necessary exceptions to the handle() method's clause, but then it says that the exception is not compatible with the throws clause in EventHandler<ActionEvent>.handle(ActionEvent)

Comment: @user6000020: then handle in a try catch block. All you're doing by posting this question and the comment above is to show us that you've not taken the necessary steps of reading any tutorial on how to handle exceptions. Please fix this soon.